# Removing onclick listener for a part of division

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button inside a division.Both have separate `onclick` listeners.But since button is a part of the division,the event attached to button is also triggered when clicked.Is there a way to remove it?

i tried `:not` / `.not`.it dint work.

```
<div id="divson">
    <button id="btn"></button>
</div>
```

```js
$('#divson').not('#btn').click(function sayHello() {
    alert('Helo!');
});

$('#btn').click(function sayJello() {
    alert('Jelo!');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gw3LqrcL/

Comment: kindly copy your code to the question... or use [code snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1):

Just `return false;` in your handler to stop the event propagation: http://jsfiddle.net/gw3LqrcL/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use `stopPropagation` on the event passed in to the handler on `#btn` to stop the event bubbling to the parent element:

```
$('#divson').click(function () {
    alert('Helo!');
});

$('#btn').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('Jelo!');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/gw3LqrcL/2/)